# how to make a timestamp array of one year intervals based on the date I want?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

**I want to make a timestamp array of one year intervals based on the date I want with Pandas.**

> example) ['1994-08-17 00:00:00+09:00', '1995-08-17 00:00:00+09:00',
>   '1996-08-17 00:00:00+09:00', '1997-08-17 00:00:00+09:00']

**But I can't make it. Pleas help me.**

Here are some arrays that I made it.

1) freq='A-AUG'

> DatetimeIndex(['1994-08-31 00:00:00+09:00', '1995-08-31
>   00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '1996-08-31 00:00:00+09:00', '1997-08-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '1998-08-31 00:00:00+09:00', '1999-08-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '2000-08-31 00:00:00+09:00', '2001-08-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '2002-08-31 00:00:00+09:00', '2003-08-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '2004-08-31 00:00:00+09:00', '2005-08-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '2006-08-31 00:00:00+09:00', '2007-08-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '2008-08-31 00:00:00+09:00', '2009-08-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '2010-08-31 00:00:00+09:00', '2011-08-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '2012-08-31 00:00:00+09:00', '2013-08-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '2014-08-31 00:00:00+09:00', '2015-08-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '2016-08-31 00:00:00+09:00', '2017-08-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '2018-08-31 00:00:00+09:00', '2019-08-31 00:00:00+09:00'],
>                 dtype='datetime64[ns, Asia/Seoul]', freq='A-AUG')

2) freq='A'

> DatetimeIndex(['1994-12-31 00:00:00+09:00', '1995-12-31
>   00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '1996-12-31 00:00:00+09:00', '1997-12-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '1998-12-31 00:00:00+09:00', '1999-12-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '2000-12-31 00:00:00+09:00', '2001-12-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '2002-12-31 00:00:00+09:00', '2003-12-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '2004-12-31 00:00:00+09:00', '2005-12-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '2006-12-31 00:00:00+09:00', '2007-12-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '2008-12-31 00:00:00+09:00', '2009-12-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '2010-12-31 00:00:00+09:00', '2011-12-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '2012-12-31 00:00:00+09:00', '2013-12-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '2014-12-31 00:00:00+09:00', '2015-12-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '2016-12-31 00:00:00+09:00', '2017-12-31 00:00:00+09:00',
>                  '2018-12-31 00:00:00+09:00', '2019-12-31 00:00:00+09:00'],
>                 dtype='datetime64[ns, Asia/Seoul]', freq='A-DEC')

```py
sw_y = pd.date_range(start='1994-08-17',
                      periods=26,
                      freq='A-AUG',
                      tz='Asia/Seoul')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the day afterwards:

```
import pandas as pd
sw_y = pd.date_range(start='1994-08-17',
                      periods=26,
                      freq='A-AUG',
                      tz='Asia/Seoul')
sw_y = sw_y + pd.DateOffset(day=17)
```

Comment: You can accept the answer if it solved your problem.